How do I keep two bones paired in one axis?


Here is a simple rig i made, its a test for a more complicated mesh. I wanted use this hydraulic platform for waist movement. The problem I have with the rig is that the hydraulics slightly veer off alignment with the joints when the rig rotates too far.


Here you can see, its no longer in alignment. Ive tried copying the rotation of the smaller bone next to the hydraulic, which controls the rotation of the joint above it. I can't seem to copy something that would align it perfectly, the copying just rotates it a small bit. Is there an easy solution? I would also be open to adding an additional "alignment" bone, but I do not know what constraints I would need to get it to work.
blend file here

